# My app is not listed in play store search results. From where?

Tags: google-play

I have an application that I haven't sent an update to for about 6 months. This application, which I previously searched by application name, is not currently listed in the search results. The application is in "production" and "live" state. Interestingly, when I search for appname Play Store via Google search, the first result directs me to my app in Play Store. What could be the problem?

Is the application live? -> yes

application production mode? -> yes

Is the policy appropriate? -> yes

Comment: Could you share the app name?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Google.